# Let's chat about Locke

Tags: discussion, chat

In keeping with [our first Philosopher Week contest](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/its-aristotle-week), I thought it might be an interesting experiment to try to execute a brief **brainstorming and general discussion session in the chat space**. The idea would be to try to come up with interesting and constructive questions, and perhaps to deconstruct some of the existing questions and answers in the tag to see if there are follow-ups that might be helpful.

This is, of course, experimental. Let's try to **remember to be patient with each other** as we learn how to organize and focus our power as a community. The basic idea would be to try to come together and collaborate on putting together proposals for new questions (rather than, say, get locked down in divisive debate.)

If there end up being a lot of us -- say, more than eight or nine -- to help keep things on the rails, it might not be a terrible idea to elect someone from the group to help facilitate the discussion and keep us on topic. (Since the idea is for this to be an ongoing process, I will try to report here to meta on the results of the experiment.)

My thought at this point is to try to do this sometime over the weekends -- for me, this would ideally be sometime during daylight EST, but I am of course willing to work with whatever's convenient for those most interested. So, if you are interested, **please let me know what time might be best for you!**

Comment: Any time works for me!

Comment: This sounds like a great idea! My only thought is that it might be better to do it during the week. If Saturday is better for you guys, definitely do it then, but I just know that there is more activity on SE in general during the week.

Comment: Did this end up happening? Don't see much in chat about it, but it would be great to organize something soon!

Comment: @Lauren It didn't seem like there would be enough participation to warrant it -- though I would love to do one for Descartes this week if we can gather enough support. The question for me is basically just what time might be amenable for those interested